# Identify Type of Record Change when Retrieving Changed CloudKit Records

Tags: ios, core-data, cloudkit

I am attempting to complete an app using CloudKit synchronization and local CoreData. Most of the operations work as expected but I cannot find the methodology for determining the type of change that is reported by CloudKit. I get the changed records, but I need to know if the change was an edit, a new record or a deletion. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Here's the piece of code that I thought could be configured to identify the type of edit I would need to make to CoreData. Xcode 10.2.1 iOS 12.2 Swift (Latest)

```
func fetchZoneChangesInZones( _ zones : [CKRecordZone.ID], _ completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {

    var fetchConfigurations = [CKRecordZone.ID : CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation.ZoneConfiguration]()

    for zone in zones {
        if let changeToken = UserDefaults.standard.zoneChangeToken(forZone: zone) {
            let configuration = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation.ZoneConfiguration(previousServerChangeToken: changeToken, resultsLimit: nil, desiredKeys: nil)
            fetchConfigurations[zone] = configuration
        }//if let changeToken

    }//for in

    let operation = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation(recordZoneIDs: zones, configurationsByRecordZoneID: fetchConfigurations)

    operation.fetchAllChanges = true

    var changedPatients = [CKRecord]()
    var changedCategory1s = [CKRecord]()

    //I thought that I should be able to query for the change type here and make separate arrays for each change type
    operation.recordChangedBlock = { record in
        if record.recordType == "Patient" {
            changedPatients.append(record)
        }
    }//recordChangedBlock

    operation.fetchRecordZoneChangesCompletionBlock = { [weak self] error in
        for record in changedPatients {
            //my actions here - need to choose new, changed or delete
            self!.saveCKRecordToCoreData(record: record)
        }//for record in

        completionHandler(error)

    }//fetchRecordZoneChangesCompletionBlock

    operation.recordZoneFetchCompletionBlock = { recordZone, changeToken, data, moreComing, error in
        UserDefaults.standard.set(changeToken, forZone: recordZone)
    }//recordZoneFetchCompletionBlock

    privateDatabase.add(operation)

}//fetchZoneChangesInZones
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is a separate method on the version of the operation that is being used. I was already getting notifications, I just could not tell whether they were update, create or delete. Update and create can be handled simply by searching core data for the recordName(which is a UUID). If found, then edit, if not create. The issue is deletion - using the fetchRecordZoneChangesCompletionBlock could not identify deletions. However, the operation family has a method just to report deletions - operation.recordWithIDWasDeletedBlock. I modified the former code and added the deletion code as shown below.

My single database subscription covers the entire private database so it is not necessary to subscribe to every record type.

```
operation.fetchRecordZoneChangesCompletionBlock = { error in
        for record in changedPatients {

            //search for the record in coredata
            if self.isSingleCoreDataRecord(ckRecord: record) {
                //if found - then modify
                self.saveUpdatedCloudKitRecordToCoreData(record: record)
            } else {
                //else add new
                self.saveCKRecordToCoreData(record: record)
            }

        }//for record in

        completionHandler(error)

}//fetchRecordZoneChangesCompletionBlock


operation.recordWithIDWasDeletedBlock = { (recordID, recordType) in

        //delete the core data record here
        let ckRecordToDelete = CKRecord(recordType: recordType, recordID: recordID)

        self.removeOnePatientRecordFromCoreData(ckRecord: ckRecordToDelete)

}//recordWithIDWasDeletedBlock
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not that good in swift but I will post in objective c so you can convert this into swift

1. First things first, if you want to notify if a record has been edited, deleted or created you need register for push notifications.
2. Then Subscribe to update add this block in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
    - (void)subscribeToEventChanges
    {
        BOOL isSubscribed = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"subscribedToUpdates"];
        if (isSubscribed == NO) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TRUEPREDICATE"];

        CKQuerySubscription *subscription = [[CKQuerySubscription alloc] initWithRecordType:@"Patient" predicate:predicate options:CKQuerySubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordCreation | CKQueryNotificationReasonRecordDeleted | CKQueryNotificationReasonRecordUpdated];

        CKNotificationInfo *CKNotification=[[CKNotificationInfo alloc]init];
        CKNotification.shouldSendContentAvailable=YES;
        CKNotification.soundName=@"";
        subscription.notificationInfo=CKNotification;
        CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [[CKContainer containerWithIdentifier:@"your container identifir"] privateCloudDatabase];

        [publicDatabase saveSubscription:subscription completionHandler:^(CKSubscription * _Nullable subscription, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (error) {
                // Handle here the error
            } else {
                // Save that we have subscribed successfully to keep track and avoid trying to subscribe again
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"subscribedToUpdates"];
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
            }
        }];
        }
    }
```

3. You will get notified in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`

Here is a piece of code

```
    - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

      CKNotification *cloudKitNotification = [CKNotification notificationFromRemoteNotificationDictionary:userInfo];
        if (cloudKitNotification.notificationType == CKNotificationTypeQuery) {
            CKQueryNotification *queryNotification = (CKQueryNotification *)cloudKitNotification;

            if (queryNotification.queryNotificationReason == CKQueryNotificationReasonRecordDeleted) {
                // If the record has been deleted in CloudKit then delete the local copy here

            } else {
                // If the record has been created or changed, we fetch the data from CloudKit
                CKDatabase *database;
                if (queryNotification.databaseScope) {
                    database = [[CKContainer containerWithIdentifier:@"your container identifier"] privateCloudDatabase];
                }

    [database fetchRecordWithID:queryNotification.recordID completionHandler:^(CKRecord * _Nullable record, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                    if (error) {
                        // Handle the error here
                    } else {

                  if (queryNotification.queryNotificationReason == CKQueryNotificationReasonRecordUpdated) {
                            // Use the information in the record object to modify your local data
    }else{
                            // Use the information in the record object to create a new local object

    }



    }
            }];
     }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you have pointed me in the right direction. I did indeed have a subscription setup - but for the private database as a whole not just for the Patient record type. I'm still struggling with the swift code for the change type. The notificationType is .database and not .query so the tests for .recordCreated etc are not the same syntax.